# tablesorter does not work when i add more columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table where i sort on the second column. by default i have 8 columns
and the rows can vary, depending on how many things i add.

The sorting works when i have the standard 8 columns but when i mark a checkbox and save which indicates that more info will be generated dynamiclly in my table then the sorting does not work anymore.

code:

```
  $.tablesorter.addParser({
                    id: 'input_text',
                    is: function (s) {
                        // return false so this parser is not auto detected  
                        return false;
                    },
                    format: function (s) {

                        return s;
                    },
                    type: 'text'
                });

                // Tablesorter
                if ($(".attendanceList tbody tr").length > 0) {
                    $(".attendanceList").tablesorter({ headers: { 1: { sorter: false },
                        2: { sorter: 'input_text' },
                        3: { sorter: false },
                        4: { sorter: false },
                        5: { sorter: false },
                        6: { sorter: false },
                        7: { sorter: false },
                        8: { sorter: false },
                        9: { sorter: false },
                        10: { sorter: false }
                    },
                        sortList: [[2, 0], [0, 0]]
                    });
                }
```

I used firebug to see what the problem was and my "s" paramater(check above) is allways an empty string ("").

step by step:
i mark a checkbox and press a save button. when that is done i press on another button that triggers a popup and gets me my table, now the table has 10 columns but the second column will no longer perform the sort as it did before.

Have i missed something? I have read up on the tablesorter plugin and I have not found anyone with similar issues,

Thanks!

Comment: do you init tablesorter after each table update?

Comment: Yes, i call the tablesorter after very update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues with what you are describing; and hopefully you're using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

1) To get the value of a checkbox, you'll need to search the cell for an input and check for updates. Note this parser will work with the original tablesorter, but it won't update (using the `updateCell` method) properly. Note this code is from the [`parser-input-select.js` file](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/parsers/parser-input-select.js), and can be seen working in [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html).

```
// Custom parser for including checkbox status if using the grouping widget
// updated dynamically using the "change" function below
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "checkbox",
    is: function(){
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell) {
        // using plain language here because this is what is shown in the group headers widget
        // change it as desired
        var $c = $(cell).find('input');
        return $c.length ? $c.is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' : s;
    },
    type: "text"
});

// update select and all input types in the tablesorter cache when the change event fires.
// This method only works with jQuery 1.7+
// you can change it to use delegate (v1.4.3+) or live (v1.3+) as desired
// if this code interferes somehow, target the specific table $('#mytable'), instead of $('table')
$(window).load(function(){
    // resort the column after the input/select was modified?
    var resort = true,
    // this flag prevents the updateCell event from being spammed
    // it happens when you modify input text and hit enter
    alreadyUpdating = false;
    $('table').find('tbody').on('change', 'select, input', function(e){
        if (!alreadyUpdating) {
            var $tar = $(e.target),
                $table = $tar.closest('table');
            alreadyUpdating = true;
            $table.trigger('updateCell', [ $tar.closest('td'), resort ]);
            // updateServer(e, $table, $tar);
            setTimeout(function(){ alreadyUpdating = false; }, 10);
        }
    });
});
```

2) The only thing that isn't clear from the question is if the table is being built dynamically within the popup, or if the table with the checkbox is being modified, then copied to a popup?

Note that the above method only updates the state of the checkbox within the table. It won't include any dynamically added columns to an *already initialized* table. In that case, you'll need to use the [`updateAll` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#updateall), but it will need to be triggered *after* the table contents have been updated.

```
$table.trigger('updateAll', [ resort ]);
```

If you could share the code that is run between the time of "saving" your checkbox choices and initializing the popup, it would help make the issue more clear.

---

Update: to parse an input, you need to get the value of the input element. The `s` within the parser format function only contains the text found within the table cell. When there is only an input within the table cell, no text is returned because the input element doesn't contain text, it has a value. So instead of using the "checkbox" parser I shared above, use this "input" parser; but as stated before, this parser will work with the original version of tablesorter (v2.0.5) but will not work properly if the "updateCell" method is used.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "inputs",
    is: function(){
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell) {
        return $(cell).find('input').val() || s;
    },
    type: "text"
});
```

This parser also requires the code within the `$(window).load(...)` shown above to allow updating the parsed input for sorting when the user changes it.

Comment: The table is getting generated dynamically when the checkbox is marked.The checkbox is NOT part of the table. You mark the checkbox and save that you have marked it and then press another button that opens a popup with the dynamically generated table. The table is initiated every time the button “open” is clicked. The thing that is confusing me here is that the table is initiated every time I press the button “open” and generates the exact amount of columns and rows I want it to generate but the sort on the second column simply stops working. conntinued in second comment

Comment: The parameter that I send to the parser (“s”) is always empty when I have 10 columns.

I deeply appreciate your answer here and I am very thankful for the time you have taken to write it but in this case it focuses on the checkbox which it does not need to. This works perfectly well when there are 8 columns and the parser and table do get updated when I want 10 columns since it gets initiated from start every time I press the “open” button but the parameter in the parser is always empty and the sorter cant sort on empty values.

Comment: What i am trying to figure out is why does the parser get an empty string? image:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/aupd.jpg/
but the values are:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/rcx7.jpg/

Comment: Thanks!!! I actually tried a solution similar to this but i never even thought of to have the table cell as the parent i vent for the css class but that always gave me an undefined value.

My attempt before i posted this:
$(s).parents().find('.group').attr('value') and
$(s).parent().find('group').val()
 but it gave me an undefined value. 

Anyways thanks alot!

Comment: Just so that others dont get confused in the future. The reason my attempt(comment above) did not work was since a string does not have a parent it is a simple value. I needed the element and got it from the cell paramater that i sent in to the parser thanks to @Mottie

Comment: My pleasure! Oh and oops, I forgot to define `resort` in the code I shared above. I forgot to copy it over from the `parser-input-select.js` file.

Comment: Thanks @Mottie this helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the dynamically-generated content, you just need to trigger an update. It looks like your table is identified with the "`attendanceList`" class, so the command after the dynamic update would be:

```
$(".attendanceList").trigger("update");
```